# luigi upstream task should run once to create input for set of downstream tasks

Tags: luigi, data-pipeline

I have a nice straight working pipe, where the task I run via luigi on the command line triggers all the required upstream data fetch and processing in it's proper sequence till it trickles out into my database.

```
class IMAP_Fetch(luigi.Task):
  """fetch a bunch of email messages with data in them"""
  date = luigi.DateParameter()
  uid = luigi.Parameter()
…
  def output(self):
    loc = os.path.join(self.data_drop, str(self.date))
    # target for requested message
    yield LocalTarget(os.path.join(loc, uid+".msg"))

  def run(self):
     # code to connect to IMAP server and run FETCH on given UID
     # message gets written to self.output()
…

class RecordData(luigi.contrib.postgres.CopyToTable):
  """copy the data in one email message to the database table"""
  uid = luigi.Parameter()
  date = luigi.DateParameter()
  table = 'msg_data'
  columns = [(id, int), …]

  def requires(self):
    # a task (not shown) that extracts data from one message  
    # which in turn requires the IMAP_Fetch to pull down the message
    return MsgData(self.date, self.uid) 

  def rows(self):
    # code to read self.input() and yield lists of data values
```

Great stuff. Unfortunately that first data fetch talks to a remote IMAP server, and every fetch is a new connection and a new query: very slow. I know how to get all the individual message files in one session (task instance). I don't understand how to keep the downstream tasks just as they are, working on one message at a time, since the task that requires one message triggers a fetch of just that one message, not a fetch of all the messages available. I apologize in advance for missing obvious solutions, but it has stumped me so far how to keep my nice simple stupid pipe mostly the way it is but have the funnel at the top suck in all the data in one call. Thanks for your help.

Comment: please include some code that shows what your tasks do and how so we can help you

Comment: updated my original post as requested

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is missing to me from your explanation is where the list of `uid` values that are being sent to the `RecordData` task are coming from. For this explanation, I will assume you have a group of `uid` values which you would like to consolidate into a single `ImapFetch` request.

One possible approach is to define a `batch_id`, in addition your `uid`, whereby the `batch_id` refers to the group of messages you would like to fetch in a single session.. Where the association between a `uid` and a `batch_id` is stored is up to you. It can be a parameter passed to the pipeline, or stored externally. The task you left out, `MsgData`, the one whose `requires` method returns a single `ImapFetch` Task with a `uid` parameter at the moment, should instead require an `ImapFetch` Task that takes a `batch_id` parameter. The first `ImapFetch` Task required by a `MsgData` task would retrieve all `uid` values associated with that `batch_id`, and then retrieve those messages in a single session. All of the other `MsgData` tasks would required (and be waiting on) this one batch `ImapFetch` to complete, and then they would all be able to execute on their individual message as would the rest of the pipeline. As such, tuning the batch size may prove important to the overall processing throughput.

Another downside is that it is less atomic- atomic at the batch level rather than the individual item level, as the batch `ImapFetch` would  fail if just one of the `uid` values was not successfully retrieved.

A second approach is to open the Imap session as more of a singleton resource per process (worker), and have the ImapFetch tasks reuse the same session.

Comment: Thanks so very much for your clear thoughtful explanation. Well after I posted this, your first proposal came to me as well, and so you have validated it for me. I also like the second idea. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use a counter like this.

```
class WrapperTask(luigi.WrapperTask):
      counter = 0 
      def requires(self):
         if self.counter == 0:  # check if this is the first time the long DB process is called
         ## do your process here. This executes only once and is skipped next time due to the counter
         self.counter = self.counter + 1
         return OtherTask(parameters)
```